# Why is appending on a preallocated slice quicker than indexing?

Tags: go, append

I wrote the following Go benchmarks (Go1.9.2, Linux amd64) to test indexing vs appending:

```
func BenchmarkIndex(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        existing := make([]int64, 1000, 1000)
        init := make([]int64, 1000) // len 1000, cap 1000
        for index, element := range existing {
            init[index] = element
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkAppend(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        existing := make([]int64, 1000, 1000)
        init := make([]int64, 0, 1000) // len 0, capacity 1000
        for _, element := range existing {
            init = append(init, element)
        }
    }
}
```

And got the following results:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkIndex-4         1000000          2183 ns/op
BenchmarkAppend-4        1000000          1933 ns/op
PASS
```

I'm a little confused on why `append` seems to perform better than in general than indexing into the slice. Does it have anything to do with omitting the `index` inside the range? If not, what is append doing under the hood to make it quicker than just indexing?

For reference, [here is append's source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/ssa.go#L2167). Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On computer one:

```
$ go test same_test.go -run=! -bench=. -benchmem -count=3
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkIndex-4     1000000    1290 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIndex-4     1000000    1290 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIndex-4     1000000    1288 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppend-4    1000000    1299 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppend-4    1000000    1302 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppend-4    1000000    1301 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  7.868s
$ go version
go version devel +38c725b148 Sun Nov 5 17:30:11 2017 +0000 linux/amd64
$
```

The difference between `BenchmarkAppend` and `BenchmarkIndex` is:

```
((1299+1302+1301) - (1290+1290+1288)) * 100 / (1290+1290+1288) =  +0.879%
```

They are the same.

On computer two:

```
$ go test same_test.go -run=! -bench=. -benchmem -count=3
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkIndex-8     2000000    706 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIndex-8     2000000    713 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIndex-8     2000000    710 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppend-8    2000000    711 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppend-8    2000000    718 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppend-8    2000000    718 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  12.945s
$ go version
go version devel +38c725b148 Sun Nov 5 17:30:11 2017 +0000 linux/amd64
$
```

The difference between `BenchmarkAppend` and `BenchmarkIndex` is:

```
((711+718+718) - (706+713+710)) * 100 / (706+713+710) =  +0.845%
```

They are the same.

---

Let's measure one thing at a time, indexing versus appending over a preallocated slice, which avoids confounding issues like memory management.

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkIndexing(b *testing.B) {
    existing := make([]int64, 1000, 1000)
    init := make([]int64, 1000) // len 1000, cap 1000
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        init = init[:cap(init)]
        for index, element := range existing {
            init[index] = element
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkAppending(b *testing.B) {
    existing := make([]int64, 1000, 1000)
    init := make([]int64, 0, 1000) // len 0, capacity 1000
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        init = init[:0]
        for _, element := range existing {
            init = append(init, element)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test same_test.go -run=! -bench=ing -benchmem -count=3
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkIndexing-4     2000000    736 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIndexing-4     2000000    735 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIndexing-4     2000000    735 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppending-4    2000000    733 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppending-4    2000000    733 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppending-4    2000000    733 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  13.303s
$ go version
go version devel +38c725b148 Sun Nov 5 17:30:11 2017 +0000 linux/amd64
$
```

The difference between `BenchmarkAppend` and `BenchmarkIndex` is:

```
((733+733+733) - (736+735+735)) * 100 / (736+735+735) =  −0.317%
```

They are the same.

Comment: The difference is 10% for me on Go 1.9.2.

Comment: Thank you for adding the second PC’s benchmarks! @Ryan interesting.. that makes me wonder if there were any changes to append between 1.9.2 and what appears to be develop of Go?

Comment: @Ryan: What result do you get from running my benchmark, which avoids confounding issues like memory managemant.

Comment: Interesting, could this be a regression or something? I'm on `go version go1.7.1 darwin/amd64` and for indexing I get `592 ns/op` while for append `1724 ns/op` when running @peterSO's benchmark.

Comment: @peterSO: No difference in the new benchmark. Thanks for adding it!

Comment: @mkopriva: There is a large impovement from `go version go1.7.6` to `go version devel`. On `linux/amd64`, `BenchmarkIndexing` 1082 ns/op to 736 ns/op and `BenchmarkAppending ` 1955 ns/op to `733 ns/op`. For example, the SSA back end now generates more compact, more efficient code, and provides optimizations such as bounds check elimination.